# why u go for 7 externalids in salesforce, i need some reason

Tags: externalid

We can create upto 7 External ID's on single object. But anyone please give me one scenario where we require all 7 Ext. ID's for upsert. As per my understanding 1 Ext. ID is sufficient for upsert then where we use all 7 ID's.

Answer (score 1):

External Id is used whenever you have data coming from some other upstream system to Salesforce

- Assume the data flows like this:

> System 1 -> System 2 -> .. -> System 7 -> Salesforce(X)

1. An object X will have **System 1 Id** as external Id in System 2.
2. When it flows to System 3 it carries external Id of System 1 and System 2
3. So when finally the object X reaches Salesforce it has probality of having 7 System's Identifier (if all objects come through same flow)

I have been working in integrating few legacy systems to Salesforce and this is always the case of storing External Ids of all Systems in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

> An external ID is a custom field that has the “External ID” attribute,
>   meaning that it contains unique record identifiers from a system
>   outside of Salesforce.

What if you have integration's with multiple systems, assume accounts are coming from all these systems then you will need those many fields. For e.g.

1  SAP Account Id 
2  Siebel Account Id
3  Legacy Account Id 4 Oracle Account Id etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking when/why/how it would be appropriate to use the 7 external Ids on an object that Salesforce allows:

If a Salesforce External Id field is:

> External ID Attribute on Custom Fields. In the Salesforce CRM user interface, you can identify up to seven (7) custom fields on an object as being an external ID field. The field type must be a text, number or email field. An external ID contains record IDs from a system outside of Salesforce.

The answer would be as simple as: *when you need them*.

For instance, you could have a seperate web application that uses that particular object, you might have an old, legacy system that integrates with that object, maybe you're syncing with another CRM?